# ¿Como puedo hacer para que Tesseract detecte letras inclinadas?

Tags: python, pillow, tesseract

Que ver si era posible que Tesseract detectara letras que no estran de forma central ya que las detecta como si fuera otra aunque no lo sea, uso este ejemplo para leer la imagen:

```
# Importamos la libreria Pillow
from PIL import Image

# Importamos Pytesseract
import pytesseract

# Abrimos la imagen
im = Image.open("example_01.png")

# Utilizamos el método "image_to_string"
# Le pasamos como argumento la imagen abierta con Pillow
texto = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)

# Mostramos el resultado
print(texto)
```

La imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he usado convert para que detectara mejor las letras, pero por ejemplo, la Q me la pone como G y la primer T que esta inclinada como una i pero mayuscula

Comment: Tendrás que identificar típicas cada letra y aplicarle una trasformación

Comment: ¿Como se puede hacer eso? @Christian

Comment: tuve un problema similar, por desgracia no pude resolverlo, lo siento :(

Comment: No uso  Tesseract ,pero tengo preguntas:1) ¿trataste de mejorar la parte que falta de las letras con algún editor fotográfico? si es así 2¿sigue detectando las mismas letras?, digo porque si mejora la conversión, se podría usar opencv y aplicarle a la imagen alguno de los muchos filtros que trae para ver los resultados.

Comment: @tincopasan si use convert para poner filtros, pero sigue igual o no lee nada o lee lo mismo, hastalo deje tan claro como esta en la imagen para que lo leyera Tesseract

Comment: Por supuesto, esas letras están así porque el creador **no quiere que sean identificadas**, lo cual complica muchísimo las cosas. No solo están inclinadas, están rotas, deformadas y emborronadas. Y en el momento que detecte que lo has conseguido, hará algo aún más complicado.